# What is the java equivalent of this KOTLIN code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm trying to do a google codelabs project on data binding in java to help me learn kotlin. This is the code, I am having trouble structuring the onViewCreated method with data binding

```
...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding?.apply {
            orderOneCupcake.setOnClickListener { orderCupcake(1) }
            orderSixCupcakes.setOnClickListener { orderCupcake(6) }
            orderTwelveCupcakes.setOnClickListener { orderCupcake(12) }
        }
    }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be just null check in general:

```java
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
if (binding != null) {
    binding.orderOneCupcake.setOnClickListener(...);
    ...
}
```